# Ubuntu загружается слишком долго. Что можно сделать?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Linux Ubuntu загружается больше минуты и в целом работает не быстро. Ноутбук Lenovo-ideapad-330-15ICH. В чем может быть проблема? И что лучше сделать?
https://yadi.sk/i/glGGcl7nfyvQqA
Характеристики:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Минус за огромный скриншот, в котором 90% - ненужная пустота.

Comment: Мониторинг, диспетчер задач, systemd-analyze, iotop, в общем искать кто именно тормозит

Comment: hdd? Если да, меняй на ssd. У меня минт тоже долго грузился. Вставил ssd и больше долго не грузится. Секунд 15 максимум

Comment: @AlexSazonov, да, на скрине видно, что винт. Вряд ли в ноут будут ставить терабайтную ссд.

Comment: дам действительно hdd. В этом случае 45-60 секунд вообще штатное время.

Answer (score 1):

Сама убунуту вполне бывает тормознутой,поэтому для неё минута загрузки это норма. Попробуй какой нибудь другой дистрибутив, например тот же Manjaro, но если есть возможность лучше конечно поменять HDD на SSD. После замены реально почувствуешь прирост в скорости загрузки.